# Cucumber 1.1.4 - How should I define NavigationHelpers module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm reading the Rails 3 In Action book and they introduce some BDD with Cucumber.  I have noticed that the `web_steps.rb` file has been deleted [Modern Cucumber and Rails](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/11/07/modern-cucumber-and-rails-no-more-training-wheels/).  I've added my own web steps regex and that is working as expected.  However it seems the file `paths.rb` has been removed too. It used to contain a `module NavigationHelpers`  where you could include code like:

```
def path_to(page_name)  
    case page_name  
    when /the homepage/  
      root_path  
    when /the list of articles/  
      articles_path  
    else  
      raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path."  
    end  
  end
```

And then you could do things like:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

in your steps.

I've tried adding a file called `paths.rb` under `features/support` with that module, but I keep getting an **undefined path_to method** error.  So my **question** is:

How do you deal with this in Cucumber 1.1.4? What's the appropriate way to define this kind of methods/modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have

`World(NavigationHelpers)`

at the bottom of the file. It will make the module methods available in all your step definitions.